# Update Table in using Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

I want to write an update statement which uses two tables A and B, and update the columns in A.

I have tried subquery and also directly updating using join. But I had to cancel the query as it was taking lot of time.

I had written a code yesterday which was taking lot of time because of data size. All I wanted to do is update the rows in **Table A** using **Table B**.

The query looks like below

```
UPDATE C
SET C.Name = C.Name + C.SirName

FROM (
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON (A.id = B.id)
) C
```

I am confuse, which table will the above query updates?

Comment: If you eliminate the subselect, you can eliminate the confusion - `UPDATE A
SET Name = A.Name + B.SirName
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON (A.id = B.id)`.

Comment: Your original posted query is not valid.  However if it were and you had `UPDATE C SET Name = C.Name + C.SirName FROM ...`, The original `A` table would be updated. As SQL Server parses a query, its subqueries, and any view references, it tracks the origin of each column and whether it is updateable. In this case, it would know that `C.Name` originated from `A.Name`, so that `A.Name` would be updated.

Comment: @TN, Yeah I made changes in the question, and as you said I believe it will update the A table. But it's weird that I am not specifying a table, it is just a subquery still updating the main Table.

Comment: It may seem to be unexpected behavior when first encountered, but if you think about it, such column-source tracking is absolutely necessary to support updateable views.  I don't know offhand if this is required behavior in the ISO/ANSI SQL standard, but I would not be surprised if it is.

Comment: Why do you want to copy data between tables? Data redundancy leads to inconsistency. Create a view instead.

Comment: You can only update one table's columns, so it just works out which of the columns is being referred https://dbfiddle.uk/kb1HD8lU

Answer (score 1):

You have to updte using a X join (inner, left or what you want), like this example:

```
UPDATE b
set 
    b.Amount = b.Amount + a.Amount, 
    b.Paid = 0
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b on
    (a.AccountId = b.AccountId AND
    a.Year = b.Year)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should directly reference table A in the `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Name = CONCAT(A.Name, B.SirName)
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id;
```